# bash, can't use xargs replstr after redirect

Tags: bash, sh

As part of post-commit hook, I try to copy all the files that changed into a local folder - using this script (attached only the relevant part of the script):

```
svnlook changed ${REPOS} -r ${REV} | sed "s/^....//" | xargs -I {} svnlook cat ${REPOS} {} -r ${REV} > /tmp/commit2/{}
```

which won't replace the second {} with the xargs argument but use it as is (creating a file name '{}').

Is it possible to replace the argument after the output redirect?

Thanks, 
Roi

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not like that, no. The shell does the redirections, not `xargs`. `xargs` isn't even "aware" that a redirection is happening.

You could use something like the following:

```
svnlook changed ${REPOS} -r ${REV} |
  sed "s/^....//" | 
  while read -r line ; do 
    svnlook cat ${REPOS} "$line" -r ${REV} > /tmp/commit2/"$line"
  done
```

Comment: Oouups sorry about that, it was missing a `;`.

Comment: None of those backslashes are necessary. The pipes act as a line-continuation character and the other lines only need a newline or a space (or a semicolon if you're trying to make a one-liner).

Comment: @DennisWilliamson: quite right... was writing a Makefile at the time :)